# GMAIL API: correct way to fetch all emails for a given query

Tags: gmail-api

We're using the messages.list GMAIL API endpoint with a somewhat large query, (500 emails in 'to' or 'from' or 'cc')...
What is the correct way to fetch all results? so far we've tried:

1. supply query first time, then supply both query and pagetoken in subsequent calls.
   It seems problematic, as it generates a small but consistent amount of duplicate entries, ie message id's that are returned multiple times in the list, and also it seems some matches are not returned at all...
2. supply query first time, then supply only pagetoken in subsequent calls.   This does not seem to return duplicate entries and seems exhaustive, however the query seems to be ignored in subsequent calls, ie it seems to be paginating through the whole mailbox, many records are served that do not match the query at all.

Tks!

Comment: `1` is correct. Supply the same query and use the `nextPageToken` you get in the response as `pageToken` in the next request. [A few other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960331/gmail-v1-api-users-messages-results-differ-from-web-ui-on-logical-and-or) indicate that there might be a bug with listing messages at the moment. Might be worth creating an issue in Google's official issue tracker.

Comment: It seems that the source of the duplicates is multiple messages (with different internal gmail id's) for the same rfc822 message id exist ...
Any idea why that is?

Comment: Interesting. Are the duplicates sent messages from the user himself? You might want to try `q=rfc822msgid:<123@example.com> AND !is:sent`

Comment: Hmmh, that wouldn't help us, coz we are looking for all emails where a list of x emails is either from, to or cc

Comment: Ah, I didn't think properly. My apologies. What I was trying to say was that there might be duplicates of the messages in the user's Sent-folder as well as his Inbox. You might have to remove these duplicates yourself after fetching them all, though.