# Get message sender address from Gmail API

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

Let me preface my question by saying that I am not a JS dev, or even a web dev, so bear with me! I'm trying to create a gs script that deletes messages that are older than n months that have a certain label and are from a given sender.

I think I have it down, but the Gmail API `getFrom()` method seems to return the sender's address in the format `"First Last" <address@mail.tld>` rather than just `address@mail.tld`. Currently I can work around this by the fact that I know this information, but is there a better way of doing this so that the code operates *solely* on the actual email address?

My current code:

```js
function auto_delete_emails() {

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("foo");
  var sender = "\"Foo Bar\" <info@foo.bar>";

  if (label != null) {
    var delayDays = 30
    var maxDate = new Date();

    maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() - delayDays);

    var threads = label.getThreads();
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[i]);
      var from = messages[0].getFrom();
      if (from == sender) {
        if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate < maxDate) {
          threads[i].moveToTrash();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have seen a question that used a regex to fix this, but I barely understand regex, never mind how to apply in this context or how the example worked (or didn't!).

Suggestions for other improvements on this code also welcome.

Comment: **Regex** is the only way brother! `var from = messages[0].getFrom().replace(/^.+<([^>]+)>$/, "$1");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think extracting the email address from the `From`-header is your safest bet. You can use e.g. [this great RegEx](https://ctrlq.org/code/19985-parse-email-address):

```
function extractEmailAddress(header) {
  return header.match(/[^@<\s]+@[^@\s>]+/)[0];
}

function auto_delete_emails() {

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("foo");
  var sender = extractEmailAddress("\"Foo Bar\" <info@foo.bar>");

  if (label != null) {
    var delayDays = 30;
    var maxDate = new Date();

    maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() - delayDays);

    var threads = label.getThreads();
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[i]);
      var from = extractEmailAddress(messages[0].getFrom());
      if (from === sender) {
        if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate < maxDate) {
          threads[i].moveToTrash();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! I'm still trying to figure out if there's a better to search threads for sender, label and date together, but as it is this does the job.

Comment: @Toby Great! There seems to be [a bug in the query feature at the moment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960331/gmail-v1-api-users-messages-results-differ-from-web-ui-on-logical-and-or), but when it works as intended you could use `q=from:example@gmail.com AND older_than:2m`, `labelIds=yourlabel` as shown in the documentation for [listing messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#try-it) and [Advanced search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en).

Comment: Here's some test input that verifies this function as broken: `"\"What happens? <in@correct>\" <correct@result.example.com>"` - should return `"correct@result.example.com"` but this function returns `"in@correct"`. I'll try and find the correct answer.